# Can I use vinyl floor plank adhesive that has dried 24 hours or more?

Tags: adhesive, vinyl-flooring, vinyl

I troweled the adhesive onto a clean concrete floor and then had to leave the house in an emergency and couldn't lay the plank until 24 hours later. By that time the adhesive had "dried" but was still extremely tacky. Will my Vinyl plank install last? Or do I need to start removing 1000sqft of glue and redo?

Comment: If on the ceiling, I would be concerned.  On the floor not so much.  What is the cure time for the adhesive?

Comment: What do the instructions say? Have you called the manufactures and asked them about this?

Comment: I though planks were supposed to be floating; you might have dogged a bullet.

Comment: One would hope, @dandavis, that the OP's flooring is supposed to be glued down and that he did read at least _some_ of the instructions.

Comment: @dandavis, much vinyl plank has the option of glue-down, and that's often the better way to go for sound and feel.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what "adhesive" is, but in general products for this type of flooring are designed to remain functional for some time so that the flooring can still attach as foot traffic presses it down. I would lay a plank, set some weight on it and see how it feels after half an hour. If it's obviously grabbing you're fine.

Otherwise, try to reactivate the adhesive with a thin overlay application. New adhesive will probably bond well to the existing, and the bond to the flooring will be adequate.

Word to the wise: 1000 square feet is much too far ahead to be applying adhesive. I wouldn't work more than a tenth of that at a time unless you're doing a shopping mall hallway and have a crew on the job.